# How to put an image behind by Layout

Tags: android

I have the following layout.

I need to put an image behind it, so that it the result is something like this

[image]

Currently the result is like this

[image]

So I need to put this image `"@drawable/white_bg"` behind my Layout.

[image]

Now, if I put it as a background of the RelativeLayout, or if I put it as an ImageView I get horrible results, 
like this:

[image]

This is the XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bgland"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonGoToMyLoc"
            style="@style/OrangeButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:text="@string/menu_text_near_me" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonGoToThisLoc"
            style="@style/OrangeButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="@string/menu_text_address" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
            android:text="@string/menu_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/locAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/menu_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/locAddressCity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/locAddress"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/menu_hint_city"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: give that background to your RelativeLayout.

Comment: @pratik Hi pratik! I have already tried that :-(((

Comment: hehe, again same issue like yesterday Lisa, let me check it

Comment: from the edittext to last button keep inside another relative layout and set android:layout_centerVertical="true" or set first view by this property and remaining view keep same as you have written

Comment: when you will set center vertical it will take whole relative layout in center from top to bottom So that it would be fit for all the devices

Comment: @LisaAnne : use the `setAlpha(0)` method of the layout

Comment: @ajit thanks ajit, I am not sure you understand, please could you explain? Thanks LISA

Comment: @LisaAnne its the same thing which we have did yesterday Lisa...just try like that way

Comment: Same as your view just created with dummy background and text

Answer (score 2):

If you change the height of your first relativeLayout to fill_parent and add a padding on the scrollView,  your code is going to work and the result will be the expected.

There it goes:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:padding="30dip"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/white" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonGoToMyLoc"
            style="@style/OrangeButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:text="@string/menu_text_near_me" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonGoToThisLoc"
            style="@style/OrangeButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="@string/menu_text_address" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
            android:text="@string/menu_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/locAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/menu_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/locAddressCity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/locAddress"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/menu_hint_city"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

ps: "@+id/imageView1" doesn't exist and you are referring it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will helpful for you please add images according to your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FF00FF" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Find A BIKE BACK"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/back"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Put Some value" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/talk_bike_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="CAN I TALK THE BIKE ?" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/near_me_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="NEAR ME" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="NEAR ADDRESS" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`@drawable/white_bg` should be set as the background to the RelativeLayout. You then need to layout everything relative to each other (`android:layout_above` or `android:layout_below`).

Your XML uses `@+id/imageView1`, which does not exist.

Comment: thank you James, I have already tried putting is as a background, but the result is the ugly screenshot that you see in my question

Comment: The problem is to do with the stacking of views within the layout, not the setting of the background. You should remove references to `@+id/imageView1` before doing anything else, as it doesn't exist within the XML file. This will cause layout issues.